# Closed set between two open sets

Tags: general-topology

If $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $U \subseteq V$, does there exist a closed set $E$ such that $U \subset E \subset V$?

Comment: $\Bbb R $ has dense open subset.

Comment: What if $U = V$?

Comment: I edited to what I presume you meant - that may now have been wrong. Please can you clarify whether these inclusions are strict or not? Can you also clarify which topology you are using

Comment: You can see what can go wrong by considering the open sets $U=(0,1)$ and $V = (0,2)$ in $\mathbb R^1$. The boundary of the inner set can't be too "close" to the boundary of the outer set if $E$ is to exist. In fact, I suspect that the answer is "Yes" if and only if $U$ and $V$ also have disjoint boundaries (this is just a hunch, I'm not stating it as fact; **Exercise:** prove or disprove this conjecture!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take $U=\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{x,y\}$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $V=\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: That was my fault I think... in any case, your example is easily fixed: $U = \mathbb R^d \setminus \{x,y\}, V=\mathbb R^d \setminus \{x\}$ will work.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Indeed, quite easily fixed.  I'll update my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this were true, then we must have $\bar{U} \subset V$. Is this always true?
In view of the other answers, I point this out because it shows that there are examples where this fails for bounded open sets with robust difference $V\backslash U$.

Answer (score 0):

Not always. E.g. take $U=V$ open. This set is not closed since $\mathbb R^d$ is connected.

But yes, it can happen: take $U=\emptyset$ and $V=\mathbb R^d$.